# cannot creat a runnable jar file in eclipse from a maven import project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I imported the open source exchange api (for bitcoins)  into eclipse (version oxygen)

It imported about 20 projects,  I was able to run the project examples ok.  I then try to create a jar file so I could run it outside of eclipse.  I got the following error "Could not find main method from given lunch configuration"

For the lunch configuration i have cTest,

```
public class cStart2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println("hello");               
    }
}
```

The configuration does have main, how can i fix this?

Comment: can you tell me what is that open source exchange api name?

Comment: I would suggest you to convert the project to maven and define the main method in pom.xml . Then you should be able to build the project